# google search appliance accurate result count parameter not making a difference

Tags: google-search-appliance

We are having a result count issue where the pages have 10 results per page. For pagination we are getting 64 result count on page 1 (ie start=0), 25 for page 2, and 21 for page 3.

I understand as per documentation for estimated vs actual results that it is not guaranteed but the above result count is when I set filter=0 and rc=1. The rc=1 does not appear to make a difference when included or not. We are on version 7.2.0.G.252

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question will attract more answers if it is clearer: what did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what did you get that was unexpected (it's not clear to me if you wanted 10 or 64 results per page). A link to the documentation you mention would also be helpful.

Comment: wolfcastle, his question is clear to me. My opinion is, one should not down-vote just because they don't get the question. If they know GSA, they can understand this question. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

filter=0&rc=1 should work for you and you should see the same count even after paginating.

What you need to notice is, when you click on pagination link, make sure the filter=0&rc=1 are carried over. i.e., after pagination, see if you still have the filter and rc parameters intact.

Also check using the default_frontend as your custom frontend may not be handling it?

Comment: Thanks Aswath. I used default collection and have stripped off requiredfields parameters but no success. URL example is : 

/search?access=p&output=xml&client=default_frontend&start=20&q=content&as_eq&as_oq&as_q&num=10&getfields=*&site=portal_collection&ie=UTF-8&ulang&sort=date:D:L:d1&entqr=3&entqrm=0&wc=200&wc_mc=1&filter=0&rc=1

The next url is :
/search?q=content&site=portal_collection&lr=&ie=UTF-8&output=xml&client=default_frontend&access=p&sort=date:D:L:d1&getfields=%252a&start=30&sa=N&filter=0

Do you see anything wrong with my initial query?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the collection not the query. The content match pattern did not include a "/" at end which when resolved gave an accurate count. Thanks for the assistance.